# Issue Rendering Hollow Objects

Tags: modeling

[image: This is how it looks in object/edit mode]

[image: This is the how it renders.]

Im not sure why i can't look inside the cups so any help would appreciated! I tried making the faces double sided and I tried making the normals consistent. I haven't found any help online so i have come to you guys! thanks

Comment: You can see inside the cups, but there are no visual cues to tell you the walls of the cups have thickness, so your eye interprets the cavity as a disc.  It's a little reminiscent of the work of the light-sculptor,[James Turrell](http://jamesturrell.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's nothing wrong, and actually you can look inside of those objects. your lamp (probably a sunlamp) is directly above your scene and lights everything inside of the objects in the same way. so there are no shadows or reflections that would indicate holes in the cups. try repositioning your lamp if the look bothers you.

Edit:
Don't feel like a fool. perpendicular light always looks a bit odd.
Take this image for example. It's taken on the equator at noon. Looks like a computer game from the early 2000s.

[image]

Comment: Ill check it later but if that's true i feel like such a fool :')

Comment: upvote for the ref. image..amazing.

Comment: Yep :P rotating the sun worked, I didn't know i could rotate the light I thought it was based on where i placed it

Comment: That would be true for every light source except the sun lamp. it is special as it sends parallel light rays. and they don't depend on the position of the lamp.